# Is this sentence correctly formulated?

Tags: verbs, nouns, inversion

http://undergrad.admissions.columbia.edu/apply/writing-supplement

Here is the third paragraph.

> In 150 words or fewer, please briefly describe which single activity listed in the Activity section of your application are you most proud of and why.

Is this part of the sentence correct?

> describe which single activity listed in the Activity section of your application **are you** most proud of and why.

I have a feeling that it should be written as

> describe which single activity listed in the Activity section of your application **you are** most proud of and why.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct. You don't use **interrogative inversion** when there is no question.

> In 150 words or fewer, please briefly describe *which single activity listed in the Activity section of your application are you most proud of and why.*

I think the grammar error arose like this: the original question was the part I italicized. The italicized part would be valid by itself because it could be a question. Then someone added the "In 150 words or fewer, please briefly **describe**", the bolded part was which accidentally turned the sentence into an **imperative**. This transformed the italicized part into some other types of clauses. Since the italicized part is no longer a question, the "are you" must be de-inverted.

The correct form is indeed

> In 150 words or fewer, please briefly describe which single activity listed in the Activity section of your application **you are** most proud of and why.